# Issue with Codeacademy course JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying Codeacademy and im at a task where you make a contact list and here below is my code i've written. But it keeps getting the error "
Oops, try again. Did you give each of your friends an address property?" And i do not know what to do.. I tried posting this issue at the forum of the task, but there were no working solution to fix this.

```
var friends = new Object();
friends.firstName = "George";
friends.lastName = "Georgsson";
friends.number = 5555555;
friends.address = ["Street streetsson" , "9011010", "Redmond"];


friends.bill = new Object();

friends.bill.firstName = "Bill";
friends.bill.lastName = "Gates";
friends.bill.number = 132123123;
friends.bill.address = ["Microsoft Corporation" , "9011010", "Redmond"];



friends.steve = new Object();
friends.steve.firstName = "Steve";
friends.steve.lastName = "Jobs";
friends.steve.number = 51515151;
friends.steve.address = ["Apple Inc", "9011010", "Redmond"];
```

Comment: With the code you provided, this is impossible to debug.

Comment: can you post a link to the question, or quote the requirements and any code that was originally given?

Comment: You may want friends to by an array and then push george, bill, and steve in

Comment: The issue may be that you made `friends` an object, and you assigned the information for `George` to that object instead of to `friends.george`.

Comment: Cannot say for sure without seeing the problem, but why are you assigning George to the `friends` object itself, instead of `friends.george`?

Comment: Oh sorry for not providing the link to the question, but i fixed the issue by removing the whole george code piece, dont know why it did not work with it, but anywats thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I had to do on that module. I just filled it in with random data below, but that should work for you. I only used 2 friends, i think that's all you need.

```
var friends = new Object();

friends.bill = {
firstName:"Bill",
lastName:"Scuba",
number:12,
address:["lol",2]
}

friends.steve = {
firstName:"Steve",
lastName:"Scuba",
number:12,
address:["lol",2]
}
```

Comment: Hello, I removed the whole "George" code piece, and it works now, dont know why it did not work with it tough, but thanks!